# Parameter hinting in Pycharm with IdeaVIM installed

Tags: pycharm

I'm trying to use CTRL+P to see parameters needed for a method in Pycharm but it doesn't work. I can see it if I go up to the GUI toolbar, click view and click "Parameter Info"

Not sure where to start when troubleshooting this issues

I have the IdeaVIM installed plugin for reference. When I'm in Normal Mode CTRL+P moves up a line, when I'm in edit mode nothing seems to happen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As expected when decide to post a StackOverFlow question I figure it out.

I had to **Other Settings** in settings, and change the CTRL+P handler to IDE

Answer (score 0):

Only to complement and give an additional detail to canyon289's answer. The option to modify the handler for keyboard shortcuts with pycharm-vim conflicts can be found in:

Settings/Preferences dialog (<kbd>Ctrl + Alt + S</kbd>) --> **Editor** --> **Vim Emulation**

Then you can change the <kbd>Ctrl + P</kbd> handler to IDE.

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl+p` works in insert mode, no settings change required.
I'm using PyCharm 2019.3, IdeaVim Plugin v0.56 and I'm not sure if this is true for previous versions or not.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl+P</kbd> works in insert mode, but not in normal mode.

For normal mode, you can add a new shortcut in your `.ideavimrc` configuration:

```
map <leader>p <Action>(ParameterInfo)
```

Then use `\p` to show the parameter list.